# What does ぜひにって by itself mean? What is being omitted?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension, particle-って, omission

[image]

The character is explaining that he got requested by an actress to join a talk show.

なんでも前に僕が出たテレビ番組を見て指名してきたんだそうだ

Is basically "I am told she saw the show I was on and nominated me."

年齢も近いし

"We are also close in age"

ぜひにって

Some googling suggest is could be ぜひにって言った so he's saying it "So I said  ぜひに" basically saying he'll be there but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

> 「年齢も近いし是非に」って。
> ≈「年齢も近いし、是非に。」と言って（指名してきた）。
> She nominated me saying 「年齢も近いし、是非に。」

By the way, [是非に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%98%AF%E9%9D%9E%E3%81%AB/#jn-125049) means 「是非とも」 "by all means".